# Using the loop FOR to change the name of a variable

Tags: php

I am having this PHP code:

```
for ($i=0; $i < $numberOfCategories; $i++) { 

    $relatedProduct = echo $categories[$i];
}
```

What I want to get is to add the value of the variable `$i` to the variable `$relatedProduct`. I mean when `$i=1`,we should have `$relatedProduct1`

Comment: Why are you echoing and assigning in the same line?

Comment: And assigning numbers to variables isn't good practise, why can't you simply leave it as the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), i.e.:

```
$categories = array("Sun", "Moon", "Jupiter");
for ($i=0; $i < count($categories); $i++) { 
     ${"relatedProduct" . $i} = $categories[$i];
}
```

---

**Note:**
To assign a variable you simply need `=` **not** `echo` :

> $relatedProduct = <strike>echo</strike> $categories[$i];